# Odd behavior with URL encoded string when used with RestTemplate.delete()

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, urlencode

I have a Java Spring Boot application (Java 8 JDK) that makes calls to a REST service. For the delete resource case, I need to specify the path as follows: `/api/v4/projects/<URL encoded project path>`, where the project path is typically represented as a parent "group" followed by the project name. For example: `my-group/my-project`. So, when I invoke the delete case, the example path needs to be `my-group%2Fmy-project`.

I am using `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())` to do the encoding and it converts the example path to what it needs to be (the group is `test` and the project is `test-cold-storage`):

`https://<removed>/api/v4/projects/test%2Ftest-cold-storage`

When I invoke the call, however, it fails. I have an interceptor that prints out the details of the request being made. It's showing something unexpected.

```
2022-07-18 15:49:18.030  INFO 21888 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       : Request:
2022-07-18 15:49:18.030  INFO 21888 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       :   URI: https://<removed>/api/v4/projects/test%252Ftest-cold-storage
2022-07-18 15:49:18.030  INFO 21888 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       :   Method: DELETE
```

It looks like it's being encoded again (maybe?). 0x25 = '%' and 0x2F = '/'. If I do it without encoding the group/path, no encoding occurs and it fails again.

```
2022-07-19 07:47:02.146  INFO 5200 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       : Request:
2022-07-19 07:47:02.147  INFO 5200 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       :   URI: https://<removed>/api/v4/projects/test/test-cold-storage
2022-07-19 07:47:02.147  INFO 5200 --- [           main] c.b.d.c.c.CustomRequestInterceptor       :   Method: DELETE
```

Has anyone else run into this? Is there some setting in the configuration of the `RestTemplate` object that affects this?

UPDATE

I have managed to trace execution in the debugger and found that it *is* encoding the URL. This is happening in `org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory.createURI()`.

I don't know if this information is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to pass the project path (i.e. `test/test-cold-storage`) as a URI variable instead of tacking it on the end of the URL. The endpoint URL need to change as follows:

`String endpointURL = baseURL + GITLAB_REST_API + "projects/{path}";`

and the delete call changed to add URI variable (projectPath):

`template.delete(endpointURL, projectPath);`, where in this example `projectPath` is `test/test-cold-storage`.